# Java JSR-45 debugger / unmapped line

Tags: java, debugging

One of the lines of the java program generated can not be mapped to a source line. That's because it's in a loop and it corresponds to a different line of the source langage each time it's executed.

Here is a simplified example of what I mean.

Source language:

```
op1();
op2();
```

Compiled into java:

```
while (true) {
    switch (opcode) {
        case 1:
            op1();
            break;
        case 2:
            op2();
            break;
    }
}
```

The problem is the line with switch, which is executed every time, and there is no way to specify a source line for it. I would like to fix this, for example by asking the JSR-45 engine to skip this line, or whatever.

Note: This is an incomplete example. I don't need a lecture about the need to do such a thing. Thank you.